# Geo stats and Ads/Campaign stats comparison in Google Ads

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to build a report that shows metrics such as clicks, impressions and costs per targeted location from Google Ads.

I compare these numbers with Campaigns stats and it does not match. I got lower number from Geo stats actually. On the other hand, in google Ads application, the numbers are the same.

(When I compare Ads stats with Campaing stats, it is matching for 100 %)

Would you know how what I am doing wrong? How the query from geo stats should look to match with Campaign stats?

Thanks for help.

```
select sum(Clicks)
FROM `ct-gtm.Google_Ads_Manager_Account.CampaignBasicStats` as stats
where stats.Date between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-31'


select sum(Clicks)
from `ct-gtm.Google_Ads_Manager_Account.GeoStats_3749539878` as stats
where stats.Date between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-31'
and IsTargetingLocation = true


I would expect the same numbers but geo stats result is smaller.
```